# Call method Restful Api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

есть Solutiion в котором находиться два проекта Lemondo.Api и Lemondo.UI

в проекте Lemondo.Api есть котроллер WeatherForecastController

```
 [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        private readonly IStatement _statement;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, IStatement statement)
        {
            _statement = statement;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<Statement> GetStamenet(int id)
        {
            return await _statement.GetStatementById(id);
        }
    }
```

а втором проекте есть котроллер, с этоно котроллера хочу вызвать метод GetStamenet который находиться WeatherForecastController в этом котроллере

```
public class CrudController : Controller
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        public CrudController(IHttpClientFactory factory)
        {
            _client = factory.CreateClient("api");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/crud/getStatement")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetStatement(int id)
        {
            var statement = await _client.GetListAsync<Statement>($"api/WeatherForecast/GetStamenet/{id}");
            return View();
        }
    }

public static class HttpClientExtentions
{
    public static async Task<List<T>> GetListAsync<T>(this HttpClient _client, string url)
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) throw new Exception("todo make normalize error");
        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(data);
    }
}

     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddControllersWithViews();
    
    
                services.AddHttpClient("api", options =>
                {
                    options.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration.GetValue<string>("api"));
                });
      }
```

но не получается в ConfigureServices выдает ошибку **System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')'**

Comment: `return View(statement);`?

Comment: @aepot  обновил вопрос выдает ошибку System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')'

Comment: А где бросается exception? Покажите содержимое поля StackTrace в исключении.

Comment: @VladD В Startup.cs происходит ошибка System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')'

Comment: Ну а в какой строке? И что у вас в исходниках в этой строке? Что ж мне из вас информацию клещами вытягивать-то надо?

Comment: @VladD обновил вопрос

Comment: `new Uri(Configuration.GetValue<string>("api"))` падает с `ArgumentNullException` — очевидно, `Configuration.GetValue<string>("api")` возвращает `null`?

Comment: @VladD да, Configuration.GetValue<string>("api") возвращает null

Comment: Ну вот, видите, проблема вовсе не там, где казалось

Comment: @VladD не понемаю почему возвращается null

Comment: Наверное потому, что в конфигурации нету такого ключа?

Comment: А зачем вообще вызывать метод того же приложения через http?

Comment: @4per а как вызвать?

Comment: Правильный вариант — вынести код, который используется в нескольких контроллерах, в отдельный класс и зарегистрировать его в DI, и получать через неё экземпляры этого класса.

Comment: Есть ещё не правильный вариант с получением экземпляра контроллера через DI